# How to differentiate postback true from forward navigation from another postback true event

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a custom components to render a selectOneMenu from a database according a table name.

In JSF 1.2 I have to override encodeBegin method from MenuRenderer class and I have this code to validate postback true:

```
@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {

    if (context.isPostback()) {         
        return;
    }
    // More code to load items
}
```

If I use this component in a page and I access directly to URL the items are loaded fine (because postback is false), but when I forwarded by navigation rules the items are not loaded (because postback is true).

In JSF 1.2 (Mojarra) this worked perfectly but in MyFaces 2.0 (IBM Was 8.5) always isPostBack is true on forward navigation.

What implications does delete postback validation?

EDIT:

To complement my question you can read this [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/727343) because I have the same question. In JSF 1.2 it was different?

Comment: Why is the check there in first place? That doesn't make sense. The `encodeBegin()` is normally called only once per component in JSF lifecycle. Having that check suggests that the component instance itself is saved in view state or even the session which indicates a much bigger design problem.

Comment: That validation was there from previous implementation and I´m migrating from JSF 1.2 (Mojarra) to 2.0 (MyFaces). I just wanted to know if there were a problem if I delete that. Thank you very much. I will delete that.